# How detect if file was overwrote?,

Tags: c++, c, file, io

In my C/C++ program I need to check if the file from what I read have been overwrote (its inode was changed or some new lines were added). If I'm now wrong `fstat` and `fstat64` can be usefull only when I use Linux but not for windows. Is there any universal (to work for complex OSes) way to do this? And also can you tell me how do this using fstat64?

Comment: Files operations are not a C++ level functions. I don't think you will find anything universal, especially for for the function you want.

Comment: You could generate a hash of the file. To check if it has changed you then re-hash the file and compare. Probably not what you want. But operations on the file system state is dependent on the file system being used (This is not even OS specific as some OSs can use multiple different file systems).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can keep track of when the file was last written to know if it has been modified. The cross platform solution is using boost::filesystem. Windows doesn't have fstat64 AFAIK.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm

```
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/File_modification_time#C.2B.2B

#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc , char *argv[ ] ) {
   if ( argc != 2 ) {
      std::cerr << "Error! Syntax: moditime <filename>!\n" ;
      return 1 ;
   }
   boost::filesystem::path p( argv[ 1 ] ) ;
   if ( boost::filesystem::exists( p ) ) {
      std::time_t t = boost::filesystem::last_write_time( p ) ;
      std::cout << "On " << std::ctime( &t ) << " the file " << argv[ 1 ] 
     << " was modified the last time!\n" ;
      std::cout << "Setting the modification time to now:\n" ;
      std::time_t n = std::time( 0 ) ;
      boost::filesystem::last_write_time( p , n ) ; 
      t = boost::filesystem::last_write_time( p ) ;
      std::cout << "Now the modification time is " << std::ctime( &t ) << std::endl ;
      return 0 ;
  } else {
      std::cout << "Could not find file " << argv[ 1 ] << '\n' ;
      return 2 ;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a code sample for you, but can you check the last modified time of the file, against what it was when you first opened it?

### Edit

Found a pretty good snippet that appears to do the trick

http://www.jb.man.ac.uk/~slowe/cpp/lastmod.html